# jQuery jGrowl not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jgrowl

I am trying to get this jGrowl working but I am not having any luck and I am struggling to find any help with the issue I have.

I have connected to the CSS and JS pages correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $base; ?>jgrowl/jgrowl.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="<?php echo $base; ?>css/jgrowl.css"/>
```

And I am trying two different methods to get it working, the first method is the method that I actually want, which is when an if statement is run it should show the jGrowl window like below:

```
if ($flag == "OK")
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() 
    {
        $.jGrowl("HELLO");
    }
    );

    </script>
    <?php
}
```

But this gives me no luck, so I am also trying an `onclick` version:

```
<p><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.jGrowl('One more message...');">Click here.</a></p>
```

This also give me no luck, but what does happen with this on is in Google Chrome's console it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'jGrowl'
```

I have tried to find help based around this error but have had no luck, hope someone can help!

Thanks guys.

---------------- UPDATE ------------------

I have been playing around a bit and I a little more information out of the error in the Google Chrome Console...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'jGrowl'
(anonymous function)                         index.php:572
f.extend._Deferred.e.resolveWith             jquery-latest.min.js:2
e.extend.ready                               jquery-latest.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.C                         jquery-latest.min.js:2
```

Im not 100% sure but I think `jquery-latest.min.js` is referring to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Which I use to enable facebook commenting within the website. Could this be an issue?

---------------- UPDATE ------------------

If I comment out

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Then my jGrowl works, any idea how I can get around this? otherwise I cant have both jGrowl and facebook commenting.

---------------- UPDATE ------------------

I now understand what is going wrong, I had both:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $base; ?>js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

I was not aware the the second one of these two is also getting the main jQuery library therefore causing the problems with my jQuery. All is fixed an sorted now.

------------ PROBLEM SOLVED -------------

Comment: Seems like jGrowl is not loaded properly, otherwise he would find a method with that name. Are you sure that it's there? Search for any 404 errors in the *Network* tab of Firebug or similar.

Comment: @SebastianWramba I am getting a 304 on my jQuery.css file, other than that all is fine

Comment: can we have a link to your script? I assume its on the internet somewhere?

Comment: I'm running it on a WAMP on my local computer, sorry.

Comment: You'll have to write an answer, then accept it. Can’t accept the question itself as answer ;) .

Comment: I had no idea you could use  'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'.  Can that be used with Google's CDN as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realised that I was linking to the jQuery libary twice by accident, all fixed now.

@Brad there are 3 ways of doing it:

Link to file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $base; ?>js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

Link to latest-min

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Link to google

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But you can only have 1 of these, if you have more than 1 your jQuery/JavaScript will fail

Comment: I am at this moment changing all of my links to Jquery to the latest.min.js one. I am quite tired of trying to keep up with jquery improvements and then changing the Links constantly.  Thanks for the knowledge

Comment: Thank you so much! I had same trouble with jqplot library and now my problems are gone!